# How to check method is exist in directly getattr widhout hasattr

Tags: python-2.7

check if method is exist in this object using hasattr()

but how to access directly in getattr() in if and check if fees:

```
if hasattr(acquirer, custom_method_name):
    fees = getattr(acquirer, custom_method_name)(values.get('amount', 0.0))
    values['fees'] = float_round(fees, 2)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Are you looking for the optional third argument to `getattr`, which provides a default value if the attribute doesn't exist? Alternatively, do you want to write "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission"-style code and call `getattr` without using `hasattr` first, and catch any `AttributeError` you receive? Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no point in removing `hasattr` check. It makes your code more stable. I also recommend to check if it is callable. But if you want to do it for some reason (readability?) it could be done in several ways:

```
# if python < 3, for 'print' statement to work with 'lambda'
from __future__ import print_function

class RightObject(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def required_method(self):
        print('executing %s' % self.text)

class WrongObject(object):
    pass

def exec_if_possible(instance, method):
    """ This function checks for attribute and if it's a function. """
    if hasattr(instance, method):
        res_func = getattr(instance, method)
        if callable(res_func): # is it a function or not?
            res_func()
        else:
            print('it is not a function')
    else:
        print('bad object')

def try_exec(instance, method):
    """ This is a straight-forward function. """
    try:
        res_func = getattr(instance, method)()
    except AttributeError as at_er:
        print(at_er)
    except TypeError as ty_er:
        print(ty_er)

right = RightObject('right one')
wrong = WrongObject()
func = 'required_method'

# This will work:
exec_if_possible(right, func)

# This will fail as expected:
exec_if_possible(right, 'text')
exec_if_possible(wrong, func)

# The same here:
try_exec(right, func)
try_exec(right, 'text')
try_exec(wrong, func)

# creating a simple crash informer:
default_func = lambda: print('default function')

# one liners, but it is not recommended to use them:
getattr(right, func, default_func)()
getattr(wrong, func, default_func)()
```

And the output:

```
# exec_if_possible():
executing right one
it is not a function
bad object

# try_exec():
executing right one
'str' object is not callable
'WrongObject' object has no attribute 'required_method'

# one-liners:
executing right one
default function
```